# Maximage 2.0 plugin : Swipe and key navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, slider, swipe

I started using this great plugin : http://blog.aaronvanderzwan.com/2012/07/maximage-2-0/

I would like to implement the swipe and arrow keys navigation. I have no problem detecting these events with jquery, the problem is to trigger "go to next slide" and "go to prev slide"

I am using two css classes .arrow_left and .arrow_right, because I have more than one "left" and "right" buttons within my slider.

I tried to fire the click on these css classes on a keydown or swipe event, like this :

```
$('.arrow_left').click();
```

But it seems to break the slider and it comes back to the first slide. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This javascript should do the trick:

```
<a href="javascript: document.getElementById('arrow_left').click();">PREVIOUS</a>
<a href="javascript: document.getElementById('arrow_right').click();">NEXT</a>
```